# Apache Redirects in HTTPS

Tags: apache, redirect, ssl

I have an Apache server (https://mysite.com/sub/en/).  It's setup with SSL on port 443, and in the VirtualHost tags:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
Redirect permanent /sub https://mysite.com/sub/en/
...
</VirtualHost>
```

Basically, when the user comes to the site, I want them to be forced to the "/en" sub-directory.  However, if you try to visit `https://mysite.com/sub`, it doesn't redirect you to the sub "/en" directory.

I'm really not sure what is going on.  I do have a similar setup in my non-ssl virtualhost tags:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
Redirect permanent / https://mysite.com/sub/en/
Redirect permanent /sub https://mysite.com/sub/en
</VirtualHost>
```

These rules work fine.  So if the user attempts `http://mysite.com/sub`, it forwards them to the SSL version, and the "/en" subdirectory like I want it to.  But if you try the SSL version: `https://mysite.com/sub`, it fails to forward.

Do I have the configurations wrong?  Am I not using the right redirect or rewrite rule?

Answer (score 0):

To get this working the way I wanted, I ended up using a RewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule ^/sub$ https://mysite.com/sub/en/
```

This appears to have done the trick.